# ajax no devuelve datos

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código que debería traer una respuesta de un archivo PHP pero no me devuelve nada. 
La respuesta debería imprimirla en un input.
Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias!

```js
$('#servicio select').on('change', function() {
  
  var servicioVal = $(this).val(); 

  //petición ajax
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'actionservrem.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: servicioVal,
    async : false,
    success: function(respuesta) {
      preciounitario =  respuesta;
    },
 
 
  });

  var $previousInput = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first input:text');
  $previousInput.val(preciounitario);
  

});
```

actionservrem.php

```html
<?php

include("includes/conexion.php");

$Servicio = $_POST["servicioVal"];

$resultPrecios = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listasyservicios 
WHERE id_listasyservicios = '$Servicio'"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultPrecios)){

echo ''.$row["precioventa"].'';


}

 
?>
```

Comment: Deberías leer sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. Este código es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques. Y deberías actualizar la API que utilizas para conectarte a la base de datos. Las funciones `mysql_*` se consideran obsoletas y se eliminaron en PHP7.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que el código PHP es correcto y devuelve lo que tiene que devolver, hay algunos problemas en el JavaScript:

1. AJAX es asíncrono, no sólo basta con leer el valor y guardarlo en una variable, debes realizar las operaciones con el valor dentro del `success` (porque no sabes cuándo se va a ejecutar, por lo que tener las operaciones donde sí sepas que estará disponible el valor).

   ```
   //petición ajax
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'actionservrem.php',
     dataType: 'html',
     data: servicioVal,
     async : false,
     success: function(respuesta) {
       preciounitario =  respuesta;

       var $previousInput = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first input:text');
       $previousInput.val(preciounitario);
     } 
   });
   ```
2. No sé si estás pasando el valor de manera correcta. Estás indicando que pasas el valor del campo, pero no le estás dando ningún nombre al parámetro (que luego se lee en PHP como `servicioVal`). Entonces, te faltaría indicar ese nombre:

   ```
   var servicioVal = $(this).val(); 


   //petición ajax
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'actionservrem.php',
     dataType: 'html',
     data: { "servicioVal" : servicioVal },
     async : false,
     success: function(respuesta) {
       preciounitario =  respuesta;

       var $previousInput = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first input:text');
       $previousInput.val(preciounitario);
     } 
   });
   ```

Aparte de eso, deberías leer sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. Este código es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu sugerencia de AJAX y acerca de evitar inyección SQL. Lo haré.

Answer (score 1):

El attributo data de AJAX sirve para enviar los parametros a la url indicada en AJAX.
La manera en que lo estás enviando no es la correcta, ya que en si no estás enviando ningún parametro y debe de ser como Alvaro Montoro comenta.

Otra cosa que cambiaria es la manera de recibir la respuesta del servidor y en vez de recibirla en html, la recibiria en json.

```js
$('#servicio select').on('change', function() {
  
  var servicioVal = $(this).val(); 

  //petición ajax
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'actionservrem.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { "servicioVal" : servicioVal },
    async : false,
    success: function(respuesta) {
      //Abre la consola de tu navegador para ver la respuesta
      console.log(respuesta);
      /**
      *** Haz lo que quieras en el DOM con la respuesta.
      **/
    }, 
  });
});
```

```html
<?php

include("includes/conexion.php");

$Servicio = $_POST["servicioVal"];

$resultPrecios = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listasyservicios 
WHERE id_listasyservicios = '$Servicio'"); 

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultPrecios)){
  $data['results'][] = $row['precioventa'];
}

//Convierto mi array a json y lo retorno.
return json_encode($data);
 
?>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo real de AJAX que retorna un JSON, para que lo veas desde otra perspectiva.
https://codepen.io/Hoose/pen/xpyeEY
y la URL donde hace la petición este ejemplo https://api.meetup.com/2/cities?&country=us&page=1